esp32 and cutecom encoding
Im using esp32 to write uint16 values to CuteCom and from there I copied those values to a csv file to be use by a python file to display an image. This works great!!
Now I tried to send those same values to python script using the serial port. I use parity none, 1 stop bit and 8 bits to data. Now when I tried to generate the image I got only noise.
i tried to use different encoding, like ascii and utf-16 but got the same result. So I guess this may be some encoding that uses CuteCom that is been copied and the pasted to the csv file. But I'm unable to get this encode due that is 'unknow'.
Is there a way to know this 'unknow' encoding? why if I jut copied those values and pasted to csv file the image is been displayed, but using the port and processing those values got nothing?
In the python script were I got the data from serial port I get this values as 'string' in array and convert this array to int. which works ( I already debugged this step), but the image is just noise. I use PIL to generate an image from this array.
Instead using data coming from csv file in which I copied the data from CuteCom the image is displayed!!!!
So this encoding must be the answer!!!
I used the ov7670 and esp32 to take an image and sending through uart using sprintf:
    for(int j=0;j<=counter2;j+=2)
{
  pixel = (frame[j+1] + (frame[j]<<8));
  sprintf(buffer,"%u\r\n",pixel);
  uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM,buffer,strlen(buffer));
  //ESP_LOGI(TAG,"%i",pixel);
}

and in python I tried to read this data coming from serial port and generate the image. The incoming data I take it like this:
        if(serialPort.in_waiting>0):
        incoming=serialPort.readline().decode('ascii','ignore')
        incoming=incoming.rstrip()

Taking the data with the port the image is noise. Now If I copy the data (same as serial port) from CuteCom and use python to generate the image, works great.
PS: Sorry for the late response!!

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Please share your code. Are you trying to send an image through UART?

hi to all!! sorry late response. Im trying to send an image a take with ov7670 using esp32. Data is in memory so I use the uart to send the data using sprintf.
